# cannot center an image inside a div

Tags: html, css

I have a top div on my page, but above my navigation.
I want the company logo in the middle of this div. however, `margin: 0 auto` isn't working.
I've tried fiddling with the div positioning to be absolute and the image to be relevent, and vice versa.

I've tried the image to be center aligned, text aligned (silly enough), even `left: 50%`. `left:  50%` does actually work but because the width of the image is over 100px, then the logo isn't centered any more, even though the beginging of the image is at 50%.

I wanted to make it `left 30%` but that isn't fair on all screen sizes.
I just cant figure out how to make this image in the center of the div. Does anyone know how I can do this?

**HTML**

```html
<div id="stripes">
    <img src="JCC.gif" class="JClogo" />
</div>
<div id="navigation">
```

**CSS**

```
#stripes
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 185px;
    background-image: url('stripes.png'); 
}


.JClogo
{
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 194px;
    width: 389px;
}
```

Comment: Remove `position:absolute`, add `display:block`.

Answer (score 1):

if you positioned the element as `absolute` then `margin 0 auto` won't be work 
Remove the `position: absolute;` and add `display:block` to`JClogo` css class.

```
.JClogo{
   margin: 0 auto;
   height: 194px;
   width: 389px;
   display:block;
}
```

[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6wRpf/2/)

Comment: There we go, that's better.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think margin:0 auto will work with absolute positioning. Either remove the `position:absolute` OR place `left:50%; margin-left:-195px` on `.JClogo`.

Comment: The negative margin is half the width of your image. This is how I would do it if you are wanting to keep the image positioned absolutely.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you're looking for:

```
        #stripes
        {
            width: 100%;
            height: 185px;
            background-image: url('stripes.png'); 
            text-align:center;
        }

        .JClogo
        {
            height: 194px;
            width: 389px;
        }
```

Comment: Works: http://jsfiddle.net/6wRpf/1/ - remove the `margin`, it does nothing useful.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because of the code at:

```
position: absolute; // here
margin: 0 auto;
height: 194px;
width: 389px;
```

Position absolute makes it to float at the parameters provided.

So try out this, this will make the image float at the center of the element.

```
position: absolute;
top: 20%; // this 
left: 20%; // and this
height: 194px;
width: 389px;
```

This way, you will change the parameters of the image and make it float where you want it to be. If you want to use `position: absolute;` otherwise, you can remove this and simply use `margin: values`.